# How to find a formula for the sum up to $n$ terms of the sum $1+11+111+11111...$ using $1+2x+3x^2+4x^3...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I'm trying to find the formula for the sum up to $n$ terms of the sum $1+11+111+11111...$ using $1+2x+3x^2+4x^3...=\frac{1-x^n}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{nx^n}{1-x}$. It's easy to find the formula if we expressed the sum as $1+(1+10)+(1+10+100)+(1+10+100+1000)...$ however when I try to express the sum as $1+2x+3x^2+4x^3...$ I can't find a constant value for $x$. Can anyone guide me on how I can express $1+11+111+11111...$ as $1+2x+3x^2+4x^3...$.

Comment: I don't think it converges.

Comment: @S.C.B. I'm trying to find the formula for the sum up to $n$ terms, I'll edit the question title.

Comment: @M.Winter I'm supposed to find a formula for the sum up to $n$ terms of the sum $1+11+111...$ using $1+2x+3x^2+4x^3...=\frac{1-x^n}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{nx^n}{1-x}$ but I can't find the value for $x$ so that $1+11+111...$ can be written as $1+2x+3x^2+4x^3...$

Comment: @M.Winter $x=10$ doesn't work for $n=2$ etc. since we will $1+2x...$ gives $21$ for $n=2$ whereas our sum gives $12$.

Comment: Why would you assume you could?  But why not express it as $n + (n-1)x + (n-2)x^2 + ..... + 2x^{n-1} + x^n$ for $x = 10$?

Comment: @fleablood The question asks me to use $1+2x+3x^2+4x^3...=\frac{1-x^n}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{nx^n}{1-x}$ so I thought I'd have to be able to express it in that form first. But I think what you said works.

Comment: Well you can if you divide the entire expressing by $x^n$ and reverse the order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sum_{r=1}^n\underbrace{11\cdots11}_{r\text{ terms}}=\sum_{r=0}^nr10^{n-r}$$

$$=10^{n-1}\sum_{r=1}^nr(10^{-1})^{r-1}$$

Comment: Can you give any insight on how you arrived at this, or is it just an identity that's popular?

Comment: @iza, I received hint from your  $$1+(1+10)+(1+10+100)+(1+10+100+1000)...$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$1\underbrace{11111\cdots 111}_{n-times} =\sum_{i-0}^{n-1}10^i = 
\frac{10^n-1}{10-1}$$
$$ \underbrace{1+11+111+11111…}_{n-times} =\sum_{j=1}^{n}\underbrace{11111\cdots 111}_{j-times} =\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}10^i=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{j}10^{i+1}$$
But 
  $$1\le i\le j\le n \Longleftrightarrow 1\le i\le n~~\text{and}~~ i\le j\le n$$

Hence **(By Fubini)**
$$ \underbrace{1+11+111+11111…}_{n-times} =\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{j}10^{i+1} =\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=i}^{n}10^{i+1}\\=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(n-i+1)10^{i+1}\overset{\ell = n-i+1}{==}\sum_{\ell=1}^{n}\ell 10^{n-\ell+1}$$

That is 
$$\color{red}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\underbrace{11111\cdots 111}_{j-times} = 10^{n}\sum_{\ell=1}^{n}\ell (10^{-1})^{\ell-1}}$$

Comment: is that supposed to be $\ell = 1$ or $i = 1$ as the lower limit? Why would you want to have $n-i+1 = 1$ as the lower limit

Answer (score 2):

$1 + 11 + 111 + .... = n + (n-1)10 + (n-2)10^2 + ....+2*10^{n-2} + 10^{n-1}$

$= 10^{n-1}(n*10^{-n} + (n-1)*10^{-n+1} + (n-2)10^{-n+2} + .....+2*10 +1)$

$= 10^{n-1}(1 + 2*\frac 1{10} + ..... + (n-2)*\frac 1{10} + (n-1))$

$= 10^{n-1}[\frac{1-\frac{1}{10}^n}{(1-\frac{1}{10})^2}-\frac{n\frac{1}{10}^n}{1-\frac{1}{10}}]$